# IndexOutOfBounds for ArrayList (Tested with multiple numbers)

Tags: java, arraylist

so I have this error I get whenever I try to use this ArrayList in this one particular text. So here's the problem-code:

```
public static String lines(int start, int end, InputStream is) {
    try {
        BufferedReader fileBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String strLine;
        StringBuilder tempSB = new StringBuilder();

        while ((strLine = fileBR.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(strLine);
        }

        for (int i = start - 1; i < end; i++) {
            tempSB.append(lines.get(i));
            tempSB.append("\n");
        }
        line = tempSB.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how efficient that code is, but I'll go through and work on efficiency after I get some basic functionality in my program down. The problem is when I use it:

```
    // Edit lines according to where the headerFile starts
public static String getHeaderArt() {
    return lines(1, 21, headerFile);
}

// Change to get the introduction text from a file
public static String getIntroText() {
    return lines(2, 17, storyFile);
}

public static String getStart() {
    return lines(20, 27, storyFile);
}
```

For some reason, the first two codes work, and yet the third one doesn't. My storyline file has 28 lines, so I'm not exactly sure why it isn't working.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at com.hathorsrpg.DefaultText.lines(DefaultText.java:42)
at com.hathorsrpg.DefaultText.getStart(DefaultText.java:86)
at com.hathorsrpg.Main.intro(Main.java:23)
at com.hathorsrpg.Main.main(Main.java:87)
```

And here's an SSCCE, without the text file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SSCCE {
public static InputStream storyFile = SSCCE.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/storytext.txt");
public static InputStream headerFile = SSCCE.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/castle.txt");

public static String line;

public static String lines(int start, int end, InputStream is) {
    try {
        BufferedReader fileBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String strLine;
        StringBuilder tempSB = new StringBuilder();

        while ((strLine = fileBR.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(strLine);
        }

        for (int i = start - 1; i < end; i++) {
            tempSB.append(lines.get(i));
            tempSB.append("\n");
        }
        line = tempSB.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line;
}

// Edit lines according to where the headerFile starts
public static String getHeaderArt() {
    return lines(1, 21, headerFile);
}

// Change to get the introduction text from a file
public static String getIntroText() {
    return lines(2, 17, storyFile);
}

public static String getStart() {
    return lines(20, 27, storyFile);
}
}
```

Thanks for the future help, I can't seem to figure out the problem. If you want something to put in a text file, here's something:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you've tried to reuse

```
public static InputStream storyFile
```

in both the calls `getIntroText()` and `getStart()`. Although, the `start` and `end` parameters passed are different notice how you're reading from your `BufferedReader`

```
while ((strLine = fileBR.readLine()) != null) { // read completely
    lines.add(strLine);
}
```

That means the `InputStream` has already been exhausted and is useless for reuse in `getStart()` because this time `fileBR.readLine()` would return `NULL` and

```
while ((strLine = fileBR.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(strLine); // never gets executed
}
```

Hence, the `List<String> lines` in `getStart()` remains empty with `size() = 0` but your code still goes ahead and invokes

```
for (int i = start - 1; i < end; i++) {
    tempSB.append(lines.get(i)); // index = 20 - 1 = 19
    tempSB.append("\n");
}
```

and hence you get

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19, Size: 0

Comment: This works, I tested it by making a new stream of the same object. Is there a more "elegant" way to prevent this problem from happening without just creating a new stream, or is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Your intention of saving on unnecessary disk I/O is correct. Why read from the same file twice? But, instead of sharing the stream/reader; read once, close the stream and and share the content loaded in the ArrayList.

Comment: +1 Well spotted, Ravi. @Hathor Please consider the suggeston of the index range check. Even if you solve the sream issue, it still is a source of bugs.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. So I'll save the whole ArrayList, and then call the get() on the array with all of the lines I want for each function. Thanks again!

Comment: @Gamb I'll still add that check into my code, the less future bugs the better. I upvoted the first answer suggesting that I add that in. 
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```
public static String getStart() {
    return lines(20, 27, storyFile);
}
```

is trying to get the lines from 20 to 27 of the specified file. But this is based on an assumption that your file does have at least 27 lines, which may or may not be the case.

If you file only have 15 lines for example, trying to get 20th line will cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

The solution to this problem is like this:

```
public static String lines(int start, int end, InputStream is) {
    try {
        BufferedReader fileBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String strLine;
        StringBuilder tempSB = new StringBuilder();

        while ((strLine = fileBR.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(strLine);
        }

        int start = start <= lines.size - 1 ? start : lines.size - 1;
        int end = end <= lines.size - 1 ? end : lines.size - 1;

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            tempSB.append(lines.get(i));
            tempSB.append("\n");
        }
        line = tempSB.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line;
}
```

This way, if you specify a start or end that is bigger than upper bound of the line count, it will return nothing. If you specify only the end index bigger than the upper bound, it will return from start index to the end of file without causing IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error can be narrowed down to this:

```
for (int i = start - 1; i < end; i++) {
    tempSB.append(lines.get(i));
    tempSB.append("\n");
}
```

Here, `end` is a parameter. Where do you get the value from? You should check the bounds so `end` doesn't end up being longer than `lines.size()`, using `lines.size()` in that case. Something like this:

```
int max = end > lines.size() ? lines.size() : end;
int max = start > lines.size() ? lines.size() : start;
```

If the actual size is `15` and `end` goes up to `20`, the exception pops up when the iteration continues to an index farther than the list's bounds. Same logic applies to start, but the other way around.

---

### Edit

Also, there is an issue with your file reading. By the second time you try to read it, it will be exhausted. Reset your reader like this, in order to be able to read again:

```
is.reset();
tempSB = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

On the other hand, a much better approach is to read once, keep the data and use it throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is you are reusing the storyFile inputstream. Your method `getIntroText()` will fully read all the data from storyFile inputstream all the way to the end and the stream will be empty. After that when you call `getStart()`,since the **same** stream is being used, ther is no more data to be read from the stream and the `lines` list will be empty !! Simple fix , define one more stream and use that for `getStart()` ..( there are more efficient ways to do this, but you mentioned that you will work on it...)

Comment: Actually, I'd love to know the more efficient way to do this, rather than just create another InputStream. I'm always trying to write better code!

Answer (score 0):

Look that in the stack there is information that size is 0.

I think that if you try to read twice from the same file, the second time you have your stream empty.